# Proving Corretness of an Maximum-Cardinality-Matching Algorithm

Tags: algorithm, graph

I need help proving the correctness/incorrectness of an algorithm. 
The algorithm is used to find the maximum cardinality matching given an adjacency matrix. 
The basic idea is to always select a node u with the least number of edges as the first node for the pair. And then select a node v where (u,v) in G and has the least number of edges. 
Following is the algorithm. 
I think the running time is O(n^2), where n is the number of nodes, but please correct me if I am wrong.

```
Algorithm MaximumMatching(G):

     num_edges <- number of edges of each node in G

     pairs = empty array

     while( num_edges is not empty)

         u <- the node with the least amount of edges in num_edges

         if num_edges[u] == 0

             num_edges.remove(u)

             continue

         v <- the node with the least amount of edges that is in 
num_edges and (u,v) in G

         if v =None:

             num_edges.remove(u)

             continue

         pairs.append( (u,v) )

         num_edges.remove(u)

         num_edges.remove(v)


         #update the edge count

         for node in num_edges:
             if adj_matrix[u][node]:
                 num_edges[node] -= 1
             if adj_matrix[v][node]:
                 num_edges[node] -= 1

     return pairs
```

And the following is an implementation of the algorithm and returns the count of unmatched nodes.

```
def max_matching(adj_matrix):
     size = len(adj_matrix)
     matched = [False] * size
     # Number of edges for edge nodes.
     num_edges = {i: sum(adj_matrix[i][j]
                         for j in range(size)) for i in range(size)}

     while len(num_edges) > 0:
         # Find the node with minimum amount of edges.
         u = min((i for i in num_edges), key=lambda i: num_edges[i])
         if num_edges[u] == 0 or matched[u]:
             num_edges.pop(u)
             continue

         # Find the node with the minimum amount of edges among the 
nodes that connects to u.
         v = min((i for i in range(
             size) if matched[i] == False and adj_matrix[u][i]), 
key=lambda k: num_edges[k])
         if v == None:
             num_edges.pop(u)
             continue

         # u and v are paired. Remove u and v.
         num_edges.pop(u)
         num_edges.pop(v)
         #print(f'{u}:{v}')
         matched[u] = True
         matched[v] = True

         # Update num_edges after removing u and v.
         for node in num_edges:
             if adj_matrix[u][node]:
                 num_edges[node] -= 1
             if adj_matrix[v][node]:
                 num_edges[node] -= 1

     return matched.count(False)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This greedy algorithm does not work. Consider the following example graph with vertices from `a` to `l`:

```
a---b               i---j
|\ /|\             /|\ /|
| X | e---f---g---h | X |
|/ \|/             \|/ \|
c---d               k---l
```

Obviously 6 matches are possible (e.g. `a-b`, `c-d`, `e-f`, `g-h`, `i-j`, and `k-l`), but with your greedy algorithm, `f` will match with `g` first, resulting in only 5 matches.